# Weird Caching Issue - WordPress + Ultimate Member + WP Engine + Cloudflare

Tags: wordpress, caching, woocommerce, cloudflare, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am facing a very weird caching issue on my site. The site is hosted on WP Engine with Cloudflare setup. Here is the complete scenario when the user tried to access the site.

When the user upgrades to pro after successful payment, then all the pro listing should be visible to them OR I can say they can access pro listing. But after successful payment when a user tries to access the pro listing it shows you need an upgrade to pro. After hard refresh 2 to 3 times. It works normally.

Note:

1. I have already reached out to the support team. They are working
   on it. I am just want to prepare my self for plan B :)
2. My site does not have any caching plugin.
3. I have already bypassed the caching from Cloudflare for that page.

   > > I have added Cache Level to Bypass in page rules. Let me know if I need to add anything else to the page rules.

I am sure it is a caching issue. I am open to suggestions on how to fix that.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

you can use wp-super cache plugin.
and you need to clear your browser cache.
I am using wp-engine. when I faced like that, I used wp-super cache plugin.
if the plugin is not working, you are working on different place.
check your file path, please.   live site or staging site... because you might make a mistake..

Comment: I have added the WP Super cache plugin and tested the complete scenario multiple times. But it is still the same.

Here is the quick recap. The user is not able to access the pro listing when they make the payment through PayPal and redirects to the listing page. The user role is also get updated properly. Is there any specific setting that needs to apply for WP Super Cache? Can you please share more info here? As you are saying it is browser cache, how the plugin will help? 

I just don't want the user to refresh the page multiple time, which is anyway bad user experience. 

Thanks!